# To convert String XML into a data table in C#

Tags: c#

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="DataColumn" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="ddlSchema" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="ddlTable" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="ddlColumn" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="DefaultValue" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table DataColumn="ID" ddlSchema="" ddlTable="" ddlColumn="" DefaultValue="" />
  <Table DataColumn="CategoryName" ddlSchema="" ddlTable="" ddlColumn="" DefaultValue="" />
  <Table DataColumn="ParentCatID" ddlSchema="" ddlTable="" ddlColumn="" DefaultValue="" />
  <Table />
</NewDataSet>
```

is my Xml which is save in data base column 
so how it will convert into Data set so i can bind the Grid ?
any suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) method for this purpose.

```
        DataSet ds;
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(string);
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["TableName"];
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to use linq, then you can do something like this

Updated: adapted to your xml, Update 2: fixed the namespace to match your xml

```
var xmlSource = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

var xQuery = (from c in xmlSource.Descendants(xs + "NewDataSet")
                select c);

gridview1.DataSource = xQuery;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the Following CodePart you can convert the XML file data into a DataSet

```
         DataSet dsStore = new DataSet();
         dsStore.ReadXml(<Path> + "\\DataBaseValues.xml");
         return dsStore.Tables["MyData"];
```