# How to store Wordpress rss feed in Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wordpress

I want to know is there any way where I can store Wordpress feed in to database? It should happen automatically that means whenever a new article/post is published from word press website , my db should be updated with all details.

Comment: @Why have you removed other tags (asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql server) ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224280/how-to-display-wordpress-rss-feed-your-website if you read then you can store in your databse

Answer (score 0):

To  [read wordpress feed in ASP.NET](http://asp.nethttp://etgconsultancy.com/Articles/Wordpress-feed-in-Aspnet.aspx)

and [One more good article on reading wordpress feed in asp.net](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/how-to-consume-an-xml-feed-in-aspnet-rss/)

[Convert XML string into Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621129/to-convert-string-xml-into-a-data-table-in-c-sharp)

and finally i hope you know how to save datatable's values in database... Just loop through the all records and save them...

EDIT: If you want automatic save then window service is the only option i can think of..

Comment: I am looking for suggestion where i can store feeds in to DB automatically, "It should happen automatically that means whenever a new article/post is published from word press website , my db should be updated with all details." That means I can write a window service which will run every 5 mins and check is there any new article available if yes update my DB . Is there option available other than writing windows service.